# Prevent mouse from being hidden in Ubuntu when running as KVM/QEMU guest

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, linux-kvm, spice

I am testing software on a VM. The software I am testing controls the mouse, and to test it I require the mouse cursor to always be visible (i.e. when the mouse is not captured by the VM software).

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 as a guest through `virt-manager` (KVM hypervisor, QEMU emulator) and have successfully disabld the automatic mouse capture feature with these steps:

1. Remove the 'Tablet' device for the VM (through `virt-manager` VM settings).
2. Run: `sudo apt-get install spice-vdagent`
3. Press left Ctrl+Alt to release the cursor back to the host

However, when I press left Ctrl+Alt to release the cursor back to the host, the mouse cursor *disappears* on the Ubuntu guest. I thought that `spice-vdagent` was what was hiding the cursor originally, but this doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to me that there is something else installed related to SPICE that is hiding the cursor.

Perhaps worthy of note: this is possible when I run a Windows guest (without the Windows SPICE Guest Tools installed), which leads me to believe that there's something SPICE-related on the Ubuntu guest that is hiding the cursor.

Running `sudo apt list *spice* --installed` has no results.

Workaround: I'll use VirtualBox for now, as this always shows the cursor when mouse pointer integration is toggled off.

---

Edit: Based on a question about [showing the cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730891/how-can-i-get-a-mouse-cursor-in-qemu), I also tried fiddling with the emulator command line, but that didn't fix the problem (the VM does still start though, so it is a valid argument).

```
$ virt-xml ubuntu22.04 --edit --confirm --qemu-commandline="-display default,show-cursor=on"
--- Original XML
+++ Altered XML
@@ -175,4 +175,8 @@
       <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
     </rng>
   </devices>
+  <qemu:commandline xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
+    <qemu:arg value="-display"/>
+    <qemu:arg value="default,show-cursor=on"/>
+  </qemu:commandline>
 </domain>
```

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/kvm/comments/16oiby0/qemukvm_to_always_show_guest_cursor/

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/730891/how-can-i-get-a-mouse-cursor-in-qemu